# How to convert a Comparable[] to a List<T>?

Tags: java, list, sorting, generics, comparable

I need to sort the data of type List, so I converted it to Comparable[] by means of map, then sorted, and now I need to convert it back to T and return data of type List. I tried to convert it to object and then to T, but it didn't work. Can anyone help plz? :)

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static <T> void sort(List<T> data, Function<Object, Comparable> map) {
    Comparable[] a = convertDataToComparable(data, map);
    quickSort(a);
    //convertComparableToData(); //here
}
```

Comment: Why not call Collections.sort(list, newComparatorBasedOnFunction)?

Comment: Also, you don't have a Function that lets you do the reverse conversion.  It might not even be possible.  So you *have* to do it that way.

Comment: Don't suppress raw type warnings: fix 'em. You need `Comparable<?>` instead of `Comparable`. Does that give you any hint as to why you are trying to do something ill-defined?

Comment: The first hint that something is very wrong here is in the annotation - why are you suppressing raw type warnings? There is almost never a good reason to ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do: type `T` should be `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. Also, post the code of the methods used, it will help understanding your requirement.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, suppressing "unchecked" warning is often a necessary evil. However suppressing "rawtypes" is almost always bad, here I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this in your current code you need an additional class which is comparable by the mapped comparison key, but holds original elements as well:

```
private static class ComparableValue<T, K extends Comparable<K>> 
                        implements Comparable<ComparableValue<T, K>> {
    final K sortKey;
    final T origValue;

    public ComparableValue(K value, T origValue) {
        this.sortKey = value;
        this.origValue = origValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableValue<T, K> o) {
        return sortKey.compareTo(o.sortKey);
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
public static <T, K extends Comparable<K>> void sort(List<T> data, 
                                                     Function<? super T, K> map) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ComparableValue<T, K>[] a = new ComparableValue[data.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(T element : data) {
        a[i++] = new ComparableValue<>(map.apply(element), element);
    }
    quickSort(a);
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        data.set(i, a[i].origValue);
    }
}
```

Note that I also fixed the signature of your method and `a` array to remove rawtypes (rawtypes are evil, don't use them).

Actually the whole problem rises from the fact that your sorting method is unable to accept the custom comparator. Were it supported, things would be much simpler:

```
public static <T, K extends Comparable<K>> void sort(List<T> data, 
                                                     Function<? super T, K> map) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] array = (T[]) data.toArray();
    // Comparator.comparing appeared in Java-8
    quickSort(array, Comparator.comparing(map));
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        data.set(i, array[i]);
    }
}
```